# Prove that 'isomorphism' is an equivalence relation (on any set of sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Consider identity function $1_A: A \to A.$ The identity function is bijective, so isomorphism is reflexive.

Inverse of a bijection is bijection, so isomorphism is symmetric.

Composition of two bijections is bijection, so isomorphism is transitive.

Then isomorphism on any set of sets is an equivalence relation.

Please, see if this argument works.

Comment: It works, if you define isomorphism as bijection.

Comment: That's what I do. Thanks, Hagen von Eitzen.

Answer (score 1):

If by 'isomorphism' you only mean 'bijection' (omitting the homomorphic property) then you have the gist of the argument.  Depending upon the context of the question you may not be able to assume that compositions and inverses of bijections yield bijections.  If not then you will have to show that the surjective and injective properties hold in each of these cases.

A function $f: A \rightarrow B$ is surjective if

$$
\forall y \in B,\; \exists x \in A \ni f(x) = y
$$

and injective if

$$
\forall x,y \in A,\; f(x) = f(y) \Rightarrow x = y.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your argument shows that bijections form an equivalence relation on a set of sets.  For isomorphisms you also need to show that the homomorphism property holds in each of these cases.

Comment: By isomorphic sets the OP means sets in bijective correspondence. No algebraic structure was mentioned so how can we talk about homomorphisms?

Comment: Isn't an isomorphism defined as a bijective homomorphism?  If there is no binary operation on the set then why use the term 'isomorphism'?

Comment: Yes you're right. However the OP means by it bijection. It's not a good use of this word but if we see it as a bijection of sets then it's ok.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the clarification.